# Using python regex, find, and accessing groups

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm using Python to (1) access an xml file, (2) search it for nodes containing  regex1, (3) search the nodes found for regex2 (which has a couple capture groups), then (4) do things with the groups.

I've got steps 1 and 2 working.  But I'm stuck on 3 and 4.  Here's an example of my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import re
from lxml import etree

url='https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/bulkdata/BILLS/113/1/hr/BILLS-113hr2146ih.xml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), 'xml')
pattern = r'(am)(ed)' 
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
x = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("amended"))

count = 0

for each in x: 
   #I thought this would loop through x and search each result for
   #the regex, then print the 2 groups like this: am--ed

    print (regex.finditer(x[count]))
    print (each.group(1), '--', each.group(2))
    count = count + 1
```

But instead it prints this:

```
<callable-iterator object at 0x97efd0c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Windows/Documents and Settings/Andy/My Documents/Misc/Computer/Python/NLTK-Python Learning/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print (each.group(1), '--', each.group(2))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 615, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I've been playing with this for a week and have read everything relevant I can find online.  But I'm obviously not understanding something.  Any suggestions? - Thanks

Comment: Are you actually trying to get the groups from `r'(am)end(ed)'`? Then just do that. If not, why do you expect for there to be a match on `amed` in each of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you aren't using your regex to search through each result of `x`. Try something like

```
for each in x:
    for match in regex.finditer(each):
        print (match.group(1), '--', match.group(2))
```